# Finding the Relation of the Areas in Two Similar Right Triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

The question is as follows:

> Right triangle *A* has base *b*, height *h*, and area *x*. Right triangle *B* has length $2b$ and width $2h$. What is the area of rectangle *B* in terms of *x*?

I tried to substitute in values for *b* and *h* to find the area *x*.

$b = 4$ and $h = 2$, therefore, $x = 4$.

$2b = 8$ and $2h = 4$, therefore, area would be $16$.

This shows that the area is 4 times greater in Right Triangle *B*.

However, the correct answer is actually that the area is 8 times greater. I do not know why. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is $B$ a triangle or a rectangle?  That's a factor of $2$ right there.

Comment: Even if $b$ is a hypotenuse of right triangle $A$ but not of right triangle $B$ the ratio is still $4$, unless **length** and **width** describe a rectangle.

Comment: Oh my god, yes I was mistaken. Thank you all for catching my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area of right triangle

$$Area_{right\, triangleA}= \frac12\cdot b\cdot h= x $$

Area of rectangle

$$Area_{rectangle}=  b\cdot h= 2x $$

Area of rectangle scaled double length and width.

$$A_{rectangleB}=  2b\cdot 2h= 4bh= 8x. $$

Answer (score 1):

It asks for the area of the rectangle $B$, so if $B$ has base = $2b$ and height = $2h$, then the area of the rectangle $B$ is $4bh$.  The area of triangle $A$ is $\frac{1}{2} bh$.  Thus, rectangle $B$ has an area 8 times greater than triangle $A$

Comment: The question is clear: **Areas in Two Similar Right Triangles**.

Comment: @WeatherVane reread the last sentence:  What is the area of ***rectangle*** B in terms of x?

Comment: Yes, in which case it's a crap question.